# How to best raise your sec status in Eve?

Tags: eve-online

So I'm getting back into Eve-Online after a hiatus.  My sec status is low as a result of my previous activities, so entering high-sec gets me shot at by the NPCs.  I'd like to raise my sec status, as I want to get into a different aspect of the game than I was in before.  What is the best way to rapidly raise sec status?  Grinding rats in low-sec?  0.0?  Are there still areas of 0.0 that are not "NBSI" that might be safe(r) to rat in?

Comment: Nothing you do in null-sec (0.0) affects your security status at all.

Comment: Even killing NPCs in the belts?  I thought that raised your status.

Comment: @GWLlosa In low-sec, yes, but in null-sec there is no CONCORD, so they wouldn't update your status.

Comment: @Arda Xi There's Concord in Low sec??? Those b****rds never stepped in and helped when I get ganked!!! Grrrr....

Comment: @DarkStar1 They're there, but they tolerate everything. That's what low-sec means. Think of it as CCTV, rather than actual patrols. Assuming those CCTV cameras had automatic turrets mounted unto them.

Comment: Arda Xi: well, ratting does (positively). Interestingly, doing missions against DED npcs doesn't affect your secstatus (as secstatus is equivalent to standing to concord), but it does affect the standing towards the Concord Assembly faction. As there isn't any derived standing modifactions from faction to corp, your secstatus is unaffected.

Comment: Dont listen to Arda Xi. The best sec gains are in 0.0. Of course you earn sec for killing NPCs!

Comment: Agreeing with @Gary. killing rats in nullsec systems rises sec status, even if Concord isn't here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best thing to do is go to 0.0 to get the best gains, i've done this many times. You also need to train the '[Fast Talk](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Fast_Talk)' skill to get better gains for killing npcs.

Because there is a sec raise timer every time you kill something this means that you can only gain a sec raise every 15 minutes in one system, that is why you move between them.

1. Find two (or more) joining 0.0 systems with plenty of belts.
2. Warp to the belts looking for battleships only.
3. Kill a battleship and LEAVE the other ships. (your sec timer starts)
4. Move to to adjoining system.
5. goto 2.
6. After 15 minutes you can return to the original system to get another sec raise.

Now you're wondering why you kill only battleships and leave the other smaller ships? This is because leaving the others make battleships spawn faster so there is always something to kill or else you can wipe out whole systems of rats before they re-spawn. Also if when doing this you notice that the rats are taking ages to spawn, there will probably be an officer npc spawn which when killed gives very valuable drops.

Doing this method took about a week (5 to 6 hrs a day) to go from -10.0 to -1.8. I did it in a Drake and used about 20,000 heavy missiles.

NOTE: when in 0.0 be on guard, people will try and kill you!

Comment: Note that as of Crucible 1.5, when multiple parties are engaged with an NPC only the player landing the killing blow will receive the sec status increase.

Comment: Do you have to be out of the system for the 15 min regen timer to run, or does it start immediately on killing the BS?

Comment: It begins immediately. So in theory you can just stay in the same system and get a raise every 15 mins.

Answer (score 3):

Your highest sec boost comes from killing a single pirate BS. So what I did to raise my status at one point is to get a set of systems. Warp to a belt, kill 1 BS, jump to the next system, kill 1 BS, etc.

The rather experienced team-mate I was with said the first BS kill in the system nets you the most sec gain. And I think from there the timer resets every so often. So if you get a set of 5 systems and just bounce around them, it's not too bad.

That being said, it's not too much worse to just kill all the rats and get the extra isk as well.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said best way to do sec stat, at least with concord, is low sec rats. If your'e looking for a safer alternative, lvl4 missions against pirate factions work to a lesser extent, and with enough of them it'll help your status with that faction as well once you get some storylines.